# How to access the `Alice` account on a Parity Substrate developer chain?

Tags: blockchain, account, substrate, parity-io, polkadot-js

The [Substrate Collectables Workshop](https://substrate.dev/substrate-collectables-workshop/#/0/interacting-with-your-node) suggests at some point that the developer chain comes with a prefunded account for *Alice*.

> Let's go into the **Transfer** app, and make a transaction. The default account named "Alice" is pre-funded with a ton of *Units*.

However, connecting Polkadot-JS to my local `--dev` chain does not come with an account; also the **Transfer** app is not visible.

[image: no accounts available]

What's the mnemonic seed for the Alice account or how to recover that account? Is there any way?

Comment: It should be when you start the UI for the first time, that accounts Alice - Freddie are pre-populated. Have you tried clearing any cache/browser storage for this site?

Comment: it's actually the first time I used chrome (because Firefox didn't work); so I don't think it's a caching issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050027/in-the-oo7-substrate-ui-alice-has-zero-funds), the seed for Alice is `//Alice`, however, it's important to select the **raw seed** option and not the mnemonic seed.

[image: the raw seed is //Alice.]

Note, make sure to select the Schnorrkel cryptography `sr25519`, not Edwards `ed25519`. The same works for `//Bob`

Comment: it doesnt look like this works in the new current polkadot js apps ? https://polkadot.js.org/apps/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-developer-hub.github.io/issues/613) Alice raw secret seed is:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk//Alice
```

Comment: The well-known keys link is broken; please update your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the dev accounts are not pre-populating in the UI check out my answer to this question: [Where are accounts located in substrate-node-template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508561/where-are-accounts-located-in-substrate-node-template/70519554#70519554)

In chain_spec.rs make sure you set your chain type to Development or Local.